# VSCode setup for multiple frameworks

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently working on a legacy Symfony 2.8,

At the same time, currently working on new projects using Laravel with Vue and other projects using Electron.

How can I make VSCode have different settings preferably per project?

I tried opening the preference (as json) but I cannot find it.

Thank you.

Edit:
Symfony uses Twig for the views, while Laravel uses Blade. I somehow need to manage these because otherwise when I comment on my laravel projects, somehow it is commented by using

`{# //sample code #}`

instead of

`{{-- //sample comment  --}}`

That is just one of the problem. Mainly different file extension per project depending on what framework I am working on.

Comment: by settings you mean code suggestions  and stuff like that or else ?

Comment: VSCode only knows folders and workspaces. What is the "project" here? You need to map it to the proper VSCode terms.

Comment: Not theme, but rather vscode will handle if I have symfony open and symfony is using Twig for the views, while Laravel uses Blade. Something like that.